# Get polyline of a street from geometry data of overpass

Tags: geometry-conversion, overpass-turbo

I have a list of street through Overpass with geometry. But I want to get a list of non-duplicate street with full coordinates, so what you need to do is merge the coordinate data into one seamless line (polyline).

[image]

[image]

Is there any way for this?

Comment: Could you  please share your complete query?